# Infinite api call when using axios interceptor dealing with accesstoken and refreshtoken

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, next.js, axios

```
import { STATUS } from "@/consts/status";
import $cookieStorage, {
  COOKIE_KEY,
  CookieStorage,
} from "@/utils/storage/cookieStorage";
import axios, {
  AxiosError,
  AxiosInstance,
  InternalAxiosRequestConfig,
  AxiosResponse,
  AxiosRequestConfig,
} from "axios";

interface AxiosInterceptor {
  onSuccess: (response: AxiosResponse) => AxiosResponse;
  onFailure: (error: AxiosError) => Promise<AxiosResponse | AxiosError>;
}

class BaseApi {
  protected $axios;
  private $cookieStorage = new CookieStorage();
  constructor() {
    this.$axios = BaseApi.createAxios();
    const requestInterceptor = this.requestInterceptor();
    const responseInterceptor = this.responseInterceptor();
    const responseTransform = this.transformResponse();
    const transformResponse = this.transformResponse();

    this.$axios.interceptors.request.use(
      requestInterceptor.onSuccess,
      requestInterceptor.onFailure
    );

    this.$axios.interceptors.response.use(
      responseInterceptor.onSuccess,
      responseInterceptor.onFailure
    );

    this.$axios.interceptors.response.use(
      transformResponse.onSuccess,
      transformResponse.onFailure
    );
  }

  private static createAxios(): AxiosInstance {
    return axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
      timeout: 5000,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
  }

  private requestInterceptor() {
    return {
      onSuccess: (config: InternalAxiosRequestConfig) => {
        const accessToken = this.$cookieStorage.getData(
          COOKIE_KEY.ACCESS_TOKEN
        );
        if (!accessToken) {
          return config;
        }
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
        return config;
      },
      onFailure(error: AxiosError) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      },
    };
  }

  async getNewAccessToken() {
    const data = await this.$axios.get("/auth/refresh/token");
    return data;
  }

  private responseInterceptor(): AxiosInterceptor {
    return {
      onSuccess: (response: AxiosResponse) => {
        return response;
      },
      onFailure: async (error: any): Promise<any> => {
        if (error.response.status == STATUS.UNAUTHORIZED) {
          const {
            status,
            data: { accessToken },
          } = await this.getNewAccessToken();
          const prevAccessToken = this.$cookieStorage.getData(
            COOKIE_KEY.ACCESS_TOKEN
          );
          if (status === STATUS.UNAUTHORIZED) {
            this.$cookieStorage.deleteData(COOKIE_KEY.IS_LOGIN);
            this.$cookieStorage.deleteData(COOKIE_KEY.USER_INFO);
            this.$cookieStorage.deleteData(COOKIE_KEY.ACCESS_TOKEN);
            this.$cookieStorage.deleteData(COOKIE_KEY.REFRESH_TOKEN);
            window.location.replace("/login");
          }
          if (status === STATUS.OK || status === STATUS.CREATED) {
            this.$cookieStorage.setData(COOKIE_KEY.ACCESS_TOKEN, accessToken);
            return this.$axios(error.config);
          }
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      },
    };
  }

  private transformResponse() {
    return {
      onSuccess(response: AxiosResponse) {
        response.data = response.data.data;
        console.log("response", response);
        return response;
      },
      onFailure(error: AxiosError) {
        Promise.reject(error); // Add return statement here
      },
    };
  }
}

export default BaseApi;






this is the component where the authentication is needed.
The api call is being executed on mount of the page.

"use client";

import eateriesApi from "@/api/eateries/eateriesApi";
import $cookieStorage, { COOKIE_KEY } from "@/utils/storage/cookieStorage";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
export default function Eateries() {
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetcher = async () => {
      const data = await eateriesApi.test();
      console.log("Eateries data", data);
    };
    fetcher();
  }, []);



  return <h1>Eateries</h1>;
}
```

Hi, I got stuck with axios interceptor calling api infinitely.
When the accessToken has expired, the server responds with status code of 401, which will
send the request with the newly issued accessToken.
The server is supposed to receive user_id by which redis can find the refreshtoken to reissue accessToken.

It seems like the accessToken is reissued properly. However,
when the refreshToken has expired too (meaning refreshToken doesn't exist in redis), the server responds with status code of 401 too, which I expect will fall into delete all authentication related cookies but rather fall into an infinite api call...

I can't figure out what is causing the infinite loop... Can anyone help?